# Display cms page in a module page

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I use a 3rd party module for the Customer Service of my website.
In this module, there is a dedicate page to create a ticket.

I try to add a cms page (already create in Pages of Prestashop) in the left of the form of this page.

For that, I create a function in modules/{THEmodule}/controllers/front/function.php

```
  public function getFAQ($id_cms, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null){
        if (is_null($id_lang)) {
            $id_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
        }
        if (is_null($id_shop)) {
            $id_shop = (int)Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_DEFAULT');
        }


        $sql = new DbFAQ();
        $sql->select('content');
        $sql->from('cms_lang');
        $sql->where('id_cms = .(int)$id_cms.' AND 'id_lang = .(int)$id_lang.' AND 'id_shop = .(int)$id_shop');
        return Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
    }
```

Then I call the function in .tpl

```
<div id="support-getFAQ">
    {$getFAQ=12} {* 12 is the id of the cms page that I want display *}
</div>
```

But when I check the page, nothing is display, so I guess is not the good way.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @marcin-jaworski to give me the way.

The solution is simple.
No need to add function, just write in tpl:

```
{assign var=new_smarty_var value=CMS::getCMSContent(12)}
      {$new_smarty_var.content nofilter}
```

Don't forget "nofilter" to print html.

Answer (score 0):

Because of good practise you should assign smarty variable in your module controller or display function for hook.

[PrestaShop DevDocs](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/)

[Displaying content on the front office](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/displaying-content-in-front-office/)

You can get CMS content by use function already made in CMS class (/classes/CMS.php):

```
public static function getCMSContent($id_cms, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null)

public static function getCMSPages($id_lang = null, $id_cms_category = null, $active = true, $id_shop = null)
```

Also i have little trick witch you can use in .tpl

```
  {assign var=new_smarty_var value=(CMS::getOneCMS(11, $language.id)}
  {$new_smarty_var.content}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, getOneCMS seems not works. I used `{assign var=new_smarty_var value=CMS::getCMSContent(12)}`. It works but the html content is not formatting, I mean we see the html code.